# BottomNavigationBar, Fab Button and ActionBar in a single layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have my `MainActivity` layout to be like this[image]
The top white bar is the `NotificationBar`. The grey color bar is `ActionBar`. The center white content is the place I want to place my `fragments` (upon selection using the `Bottombar`)

This is my layout file for the same. The Toolbar is hiding behind the notificationbar after installing the app on my device. What changes shall I do to make it work?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:foregroundGravity="top"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_dark" />

</FrameLayout>

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"
    app:bb_inActiveTabAlpha="0.6"
    app:bb_inActiveTabColor="#ffffff"
    app:bb_activeTabColor="#ffffff"
    app:bb_behavior="shifting|underNavbar"/>
```

Comment: Seems your layout structure is fine. Can you please post the styles.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Try this xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        android:gravity="top">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:useCompatPadding="true" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!--<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/bottomBar"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="56dp"-->
    <!--android:gravity="bottom"-->
    <!--android:foregroundGravity="bottom"-->
    <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom"-->
    <!--app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs"-->
    <!--app:bb_inActiveTabAlpha="0.6"-->
    <!--app:bb_inActiveTabColor="#ffffff"-->
    <!--app:bb_activeTabColor="#ffffff"-->
    <!--app:bb_behavior="shifting|underNavbar"/>-->

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/main">


    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Bottom navigation view Helper class :

```
public class BottomNavigationViewHelper {
    public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
        BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
        try {
            Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
            shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
            shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                BottomNavigationItemView item = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(i);
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setShiftingMode(false);
                // set once again checked value, so view will be updated
                //noinspection RestrictedApi
                item.setChecked(item.getItemData().isChecked());
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
        }
    }
}
```

and in java file

```
 BottomNavigationView bnav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomnav);
       BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bnav);
```

Comment: Hi Vishva! I tried your solution and got a white bottombar. Can you please identify what the problem is? http://i.imgur.com/ffcSc1X.png

Comment: @shikharbansal see my edited answer. as android bottomnavigation is by default support shifting mode. you can disable it using this helper class and this java class line. it will solve your problem.

Comment: @shikharbansal Please vote up my answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks again for looking into the matter. I am still not able to clear the issue as the problem is the white bottom(where there are back , home and recent apps buttons) not the shifting of BottomnavigationBar.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lm7S.jpg - see this image when there is no bottom navigation(back,home,recent apps) it also shows perfect. it may be your phone navigation color is white. try to run in different devices. I have checked it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example of BottomNavigationBar, Fab Button, ActionBar and Navigation Drawer also in a single layout. Hope it might help you...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.alisonstech.pos.ui.HomeActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/text_color_light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/home_navigation" />

        <io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
            app:fabMenu="@menu/fab_menu"
            app:miniFabBackgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:miniFabDrawableTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:miniFabTitleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nvView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Why to use library when we can acheive it by android default widgets. Library will increase the size of apk.

Comment: I've used only one external library that is  FabSpeedDial for multiple actions all others are from android design libraries you need to implement when you designing a material ui using material components like NavigationView  , CoordinatorLayout , BottomNavigationView , AppBar etc ...

Comment: you can use `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` instead of `io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial`

Comment: I have the same code. `BottomNavigationView` covers `FloatingActionButton` how force fab button to be placed above navigation? What I'm doing wrong?